# Why on assignment declaration declare an interface on the left and an implementing class on the right?

Tags: c#, java, oop, inheritance, interface

I've noticed this pattern a lot in Java and C# code, so I assume it's a 'best practice' for some reason, but I'm not sure why. So, for example in Java I might see...

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This being only declared in one place (obviously), and only applicable in one block of code, what's the point? Why not say...

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

...?

Comment: There are lots of duplicates

Comment: A popular reason is so that you can change the type (to another one that implements that interface) without breaking code.

Comment: Another one (.NET only): `IEnumerable<T>` cannot modify the collection since add,remove or clear methods are from the child interface `ICollection<T>`. So if you want it to be immutable use the base interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is best practice. 
Because later in your code you can change implementation with `LinkedList<String>` or `CustomListImpl<String>` without changing client code

Imagine that you use some third party library that has method:

```
ArrayList<Document> getAllDocuments(){...}
```

In this case if library author will change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`, it will break all your code(you will have compilation errors);

```
ArrayList<Document> list = getAllDocuments()//compilation error here
```

If library method would be declared with interface

```
List<Document> getAllDocuments(){...}
```

And author will change implementation to `LinkedList` your code will work fine, example:

```
List<Document> list = getAllDocuments()//you do not worry here about implementation
```

So using `Interfaces` allows you to create program on **abstraction level** instead of **implementation level**

Answer (score 1):

Because a `List<String>` declares an object which is able to respond to all methods that are available to the `List` interface. An `ArrayList` could have more methods which are available for that specific implementation.

Declaring

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

would allow you to use any method that is even specific of `ArrayList`. But let's think that one day you realize that an `ArrayList` is not the best solution for your problem. If you had

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then you could directly change it to

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

with the guarantee to not break anything else in the code, because `list` was used just as a `List<String>` so you weren't using any extra functionality on it.

In general, **less you assume on a specific type, the best it is**. This because you are interfacing with the type just with an interface so you don't care what the exact type is or what extra functionality it has, **you just care about methods offered by the interfaces**. Of course this is not always possible because sometimes you need to use that specific functionality.

Comment: I realize my question is a duplicate, but nice answer, thanks.